# Trigger/run Selenium script from Postman (or similar tool)

Tags: selenium, postman, postman-pre-request-script

1. How could a Selenium script be triggered / run from Postman (or a similar tool) ?
2. More generally:
   How could an external script be launched from Postman (or a similar tool) ?

Comment: Your goal seems strange to me. Why do you want to launch from Postman? What are some "similar tools" you are considering? There are pre-request scripts that could probably work but I'm really curious why you are trying to do this.

Comment: expose the script through a api and then run it from postman

Comment: @C.Peck: I would like to have a Postman test suite that explores a bit the Spotify Web API. But to do that, an access token is needed for most of the API requests. **The token expires quite quickly**, so the Postman test suite would depend on manually providing a fresh token, after each expiry.

Comment: @C.Peck: Please resume your answer whenever available.